# Cannot open more than one ms access 2013 databases at the same time

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

When using access 2007 I can open many different database files at the same time.  Now, on access 2013, whenever I try to open a second database, access closes the first one and opens the second one.  So, I only can have one database open at any given time, just only one access window... How am I supposed to copy forms, tables, queries, and other database objects from one database to another??

Comment: How are you opening the databases? I have two instances of Access 2013 open right now, with a different database open in each one. I opened them by double-clicking the icons of the .accdb files in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a single instance of Access, you can have only one database open at a time. In other words, you can't start Access, open one database, and then open another database without closing the first database. However, you can run multiple instances of Access at the same time, each with a database open in it. Each time you start Access, you open an instance of it. So to open two Access databases at the same time, start Access and open the first Access database, then start Access again and open the second database in the second instance of the program.

taken from

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/opening-multiple-databases-at-the-same-time-in-access-HA001055092.aspx

Comment: +1 for a good answer. As far as I know this has always been the case, and indeed the article you cited applies to versions as far back as Access 97. However, this question suggests that there is a difference in behaviour between Access 2007 and Access 2013. I'm not sure that there is one, but it would be interesting to know.

Comment: You're right... it was a matter of knowing how to open a new program instance. If you open it from the programs menu it only focuses on the already opened access window.  What I did was to right clic on the access icon on the task bar and chose "Access 2013", then it opened a new empty access instance. thx for this quick answer!

Comment: The problem is, it is impossible to launch a SECOND instance of Access (certainly not from Windows 8.1).  This is the problem!  If I try to launch a second instance from the Windows Start Menu, it takes me to the first instance instead of launching a new second instance.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to solve your initial problem, namely the copying of objects from one database to another is to use the import facility that you will find in the tab "External Data" which is divided into to sections, one having commands relating to imports (and linking) and the other to exports. In the imports section click the "Access" icon an follow up with the wizard. Note that linking is optional.

P M Jugwunth